# what is the correct way to add block as a child of an another block in xml in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have two custom magento blocks called *"exe2"* and *"example"*.
The exe2 block gets the contents of the example block using the *getChildHtml* function, but it keeps just returning empty strings to me and only the exe2 contents make it to the screen.

Here is my code my code:

exe2 xml file:

```
<layout version = "0.1.0">

<test_example_view>


    <block type = "exemplum_mod2/exe2" name = "exemplum.mod2.exe2"  template="exemplum/mod2/exe2.phtml">
        <reference name = "exemplum.mod2.exe2">
            <block type="exemplum/example" name="exemplum.example" template="exemplum/example1/example.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </block>


</test_example_view>
```

example xml file

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>

    <block type="exemplum/example" name="exemplum.example" template="exemplum/example1/example.phtml" />        

</default>
```

Here is the exe2 phtml file that has the getChildHtml call in it:

```
<h1> 2nd </h1>
<?php

    echo $this->getMessage();
    echo $this->getChildHtml("exemplum.mod2.exe2");

?>

hello
```

example.phtml file:

```
<h1>Hello there</h1>
```

And finally heres the controller file that loads the blocks:

```
<?php



class exemplum_example1_ExampleController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{


    public function viewAction(){

        $this->loadLayout();

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('exemplum_mod2/exe2');
        $block->setTemplate("exemplum/mod2/exe2.phtml");


        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

        $this->renderLayout();

    }



}
```

What is the correct way to add one block as the child block of a another block in the xml file? Every solution that i found on google didn't seem to work in my case so what am i doing wrong here?